# HTML list-style-type dash

Tags: html, css, xhtml, html-lists

Is there a way to create a list-style in HTML with a dash (i.e. - or – `&ndash;` or — `&mdash;`) i.e.

```
<ul>
  <li>abc</li>
</ul>
```

Outputting:

```
- abc
```

It's occurred to me to do this with something like `li:before { content: "-" };`, though I don't know the cons of that option (and would be much obliged for feedback).

More generically, I wouldn't mind knowing how to use generic characters for list items.

Comment: since dash is commonly used in lists why it's not included by default in css?

Comment: more importantly, why is there armenian numbering and katakana...but not dashes?

Comment: `ul { list-style-type: '- '; }` and `ul { list-style: '- '; }` seem both to work now. –– And yes, the proposed `list-style-type: dash;` should be implemented in the CSS-Standards. – Maybe in 2032. ;)

Answer (score 78, accepted):

In my case adding this code to CSS

```
ul {
    list-style-type: '- ';
}
```

was enough. Simple as it is.

Comment: Assuming this is a relatively new addition to CSS since I can't find another answer that mentions it, but this really should be the accepted answer these days.

Comment: This is now also supported in Chrome (as of 79 I believe): https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5893875400966144 and https://caniuse.com/#feat=mdn-css_properties_list-style-type_string

Comment: Get this answer to the top!

Comment: I just noticed the space after “En dash” that is a nice and simple solution to the problem of dash being visually too close to the content beginning.

Answer (score 258):

There is an easy fix (text-indent) to keep the indented list effect with the `:before` pseudo class.

```css
ul {
  margin: 0;
}
ul.dashed {
  list-style-type: none;
}
ul.dashed > li {
  text-indent: -5px;
}
ul.dashed > li:before {
  content: "-";
  text-indent: -5px;
}
```

```html
Some text
<ul class="dashed">
  <li>First</li>
  <li>Second</li>
  <li>Third</li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li>First</li>
  <li>Second</li>
  <li>Third</li>
</ul>
Last text
```

Comment: Works, but don't forget to put the `list-style-type: none;` to the `<ul>` element.

Comment: without indentation just `ul li:before{ content:"- ";}`

Comment: I prefer to add `display: block; float: left;` to the `li:before` which can more easily pull it out of content flow, otherwise it's pretty hard/buggy to get the first and subsequent lines to line up correctly. Or Keyan Zhang's answer also does this with absolute positioning.

Comment: What would be a HTML-only solution similar to the one you proposed?

Answer (score 116):

You could use `:before` and `content:` bearing in mind that this is not supported in IE 7 or below. If you're OK with that then this is your best solution. See the [Can I Use](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-gencontent) or [QuirksMode](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html) CSS compatibility tables for full details.

A slightly nastier solution that should work in older browsers is to use an image for the bullet point and just make the image look like a dash. See the [W3C `list-style-image` page](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/list-style-type) for examples.

Comment: The problem with `:before` is that when the list items spans several lines, the indent on the 2nd line starts where the dash is, thus ruining the indented list effect. You need to use hanging indents to avoid this. See this: http://www.alistapart.com/articles/taminglists/

Comment: To place mdash in `content` use `content: "\2014\a0"`

Comment: See the answer of @three , which is more generic and less verbose!

Comment: There is no code example shown in this answer, wonder why is this marked as the solution. IMHO the answer by @three is much better and should be accepted as the answer.

Answer (score 90):

Here's a version without any position relative or absolute and without text-indent:

```
ul.dash {
    list-style: none;
    margin-left: 0;
    padding-left: 1em;
}
ul.dash > li:before {
    display: inline-block;
    content: "-";
    width: 1em;
    margin-left: -1em;
}
```

Enjoy ;)

Comment: great! i'd suggest 'ul.dash > li:before'. otherwise inner uls get messed up.

Comment: I prefer to add `display: block; float: left;` to the `li:before` which can more easily pull it out of content flow, otherwise it's pretty hard/buggy to get the first and subsequent lines to line up correctly. Or Keyan Zhang's answer also does this with absolute positioning.

Comment: I use this as a navigation `.active` class with `li:before { visibility: hidden; }` and `li.active:before { visibility: visible; }`

Comment: Best suggestion imo!

Answer (score 64):

Use this:

```
ul
{
    list-style: square inside url('data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhBQAKAIABAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAEALAAAAAAFAAoAAAIIjI+ZwKwPUQEAOw==');
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not respect css text's colors.

Comment: The only possible solution for emails

Comment: Its not working for both Gmail(Nov 2018) and Outlook 2016 now.

Comment: Great simple solution, any simple way to make the dash longer?

Answer (score 38):

```
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

ul > li:before {
  content: "–"; /* en dash */
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: -1.1em; 
}
```

demo [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/keyanzhang/3f2vb/)

Answer (score 33):

Let me add my version too, mostly for me to find my own preferred solution again:

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  /*use padding to move list item from left to right*/
  padding-left: 1em;
}

ul li:before {
  content: "–";
  position: absolute;
  /*change margin to move dash around*/
  margin-left: -1em;
}
```

```html
<!-- 
Just use the following CSS to turn your
common disc lists into a list-style-type: 'dash' 
Give credit and enjoy!
-->
Some text
<ul>
  <li>One</li>
  <li>Very</li>
  <li>Simple Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.</li>
  <li>Approach!</li>
</ul>
```

https://codepen.io/burningTyger/pen/dNzgrQ

Comment: IMHO its the best solution so far. Thx for sharing!

Answer (score 21):

```
ul {
  list-style-type: '-';
}
```

You can refer to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/list-style-type)

Answer (score 11):

One of the top answers did not work for me, because, after a little bit trial and error, the li:before also needed the css rule display:inline-block.

So this is a fully working answer for me:

```
ul.dashes{
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 2em;
  li{
    &:before{
      content: "-";
      text-indent: -2em;
      display: inline-block;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: this is written in LESS/SASS.

Answer (score 7):

```
ul {
margin:0;
list-style-type: none;
}
li:before { content: "- ";}
```

Comment: probably 
```
ul {
margin:0;
list-style-type: none;
}
ul li:before { content: "- ";} 
```

otherwise it affects ol lists as well

Answer (score 6):

Here is my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r8a9C/2/) version:

The (modernizr) class `.generatedcontent` on `<html>` practically means IE8+ and every other sane browser.

```
<html class="generatedcontent">
  <ul class="ul-dash hanging">
    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet stack o verflow dot com</li>
    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet stack o verflow dot com</li>
  </ul>
```

CSS:

```
.ul-dash {
  margin: 0;
}

.ul-dash {
  margin-left: 0em;
  padding-left: 1.5em;
}

.ul-dash.hanging > li { /* remove '>' for IE6 support */
  padding-left: 1em;
  text-indent: -1em;
}  

.generatedcontent .ul-dash {
  list-style: none;
}
.generatedcontent .ul-dash > li:before {
  content: "–";
  text-indent: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 0;
  position: relative;
  left: -1.5em;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Use `list-style-type`, which has 93% global support as of march 2023.

> The list-style-type CSS property sets the marker (such as a disc, character, or custom counter style) of a list item element.

```
ul {
 list-style-type: "- "
}
```

*Remember to add a single space after the **-***

[image]

#### References

1. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/list-style-type
2. https://caniuse.com/?search=list-style-type%3Astring

Answer (score 4):

Another way:

```
li:before {
  content: '\2014\00a0\00a0'; /* em-dash followed by two non-breaking spaces*/
}
li {
  list-style: none;
  text-indent: -1.5em;
  padding-left: 1.5em;    
}
```

Answer (score 4):

For anyone having this problem today, the solution is simply:

list-style: "- "

Answer (score 4):

**HTML**

```
<ul>
  <li>One</li>
  <li>Very</li>
  <li>Simple</li>
  <li>Approach!</li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

ul li:before {
  content: '-';
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: -20px;
}`
```

Answer (score 3):

I do not know if there is a better way, but you can create a custom bullet point graphic depicting a dash, and then let the browser know you want to use it in your list with the [list-style-type](http://www.w3schools.com/CSS/pr_list-style-type.asp) property. An example on that page shows how to use a graphic as a bullet.

I have never tried to use :before in the way you have, although it may work. The downside is that it will not be supported by some older browsers. My gut reaction is that this is still important enough to take into consideration. In the future, this may not be as important.

EDIT: I have done a little testing with the OP's approach. In IE8, I couldn't get the technique to work, so it definitely is not yet cross-browser. Moreover, in Firefox and Chrome, setting list-style-type to none in conjunction appears to be ignored.

Answer (score 3):

My solution is in adding extra span tag with mdash in it:

```
<ul class="mdash-list">
    <li><span class="mdash-icon">&mdash;</span>ABC</li>
    <li><span class="mdash-icon">&mdash;</span>XYZ</li>
</ul>
```

and adding to css:

```
ul.mdash-list 
{
    list-style:none;
}

ul.mdash-list  li
{
    position:relative;
}

ul.mdash-list li .mdash-icon
{
    position:absolute;
    left:-20px;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

CSS:

```
li:before {
  content: '— ';
  margin-left: -20px;
}

li {
  margin-left: 20px;
  list-style: none;
}
```

HTML:

```
<ul>
  <li>foo</li>
  <li>bar</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: this does not work for items that span more than one line

Answer (score 3):

You can just set li::marker like so:

```css
li::marker {
   content: '- ';
}
```

Comment: won't work on Safari https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/::marker

Answer (score 3):

- When using symbols that do not exist on the keyboard, see HTML entities and use CSS code values for the `list-style-type` property. See the list of CSS codes at [HTML Character Entity References](https://unicode-table.com/en/html-entities/#block-arrows) for different symbols.
- For symbols that are there on the keyboard, use the keyboard symbols directly as values to the `list-style-type` property.

See example code below:

```html
<!-- See HTML entities for symbols NOT on the keyboard -->
<h3>HTML Entities: Long Rightwards Double Arrow</h3>
<ul style="list-style-type: '\27F9';">
  <li>One</li>
  <li>Two</li>
  <li>Three</li>
</ul>

<!-- Use symbols on the keyboard directly -->
<h3>Dash symbol on the keyboard</h3>
<ul style="list-style-type: '-';">
  <li>One</li>
  <li>Two</li>
  <li>Three</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using lu li, used `dl (definition list) and dd`. 
`<dd>` can be defined using standard css style such as `{color:blue;font-size:1em;}` and use as marker whatever symbol you place after the html tag. It works like ul li, but allows you to use any symbol, you just have to indent it to get the indented list effect you normally get with `ul li`.

```
CSS:
dd{text-indent:-10px;}

HTML
<dl>
<dd>- One</dd>
<dd>- Two</dd>
<dd>- Three</dd></dl>
```

Gives you much cleaner code! That way, you could use any type of character as marker! Indent is of about `-10px` and it works perfect!

Comment: This is quite bad for two reasons. Firstly, you're putting your bullet characters directly in the text, mixing content and style. Secondly, you're misusing the dl element, here's an article on [correct use](http://html5doctor.com/the-dl-element/).

Answer (score 2):

What worked for me was

```
<ul>
    <li type= "none">  &ndash; line 1 </li>
    <li type= "none">  &ndash; line 2 </li>
    <li type= "none">  &ndash; line 3 </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Good thinking bro.

Comment: exactly what i needed for inline styling of rss feed output, tx