# Create list with different style in MediaWiki

Tags: mediawiki

In MediaWiki, I would like to create a list with a different style, let's say a bullet list with plus icon instead of square icon.
What should I do:

- Change the css style, but I don't want to change the css style of all bullet lists just specific ones
- Create a Template, but it doesn't seem to fit the problem
- Create a parser extension, I read the `includes/parser/BlockLevelPass.php` but I don't really understood how MediaWiki parses the bullet list.

Example:

```
⊕ Element1
⊕ Element2
```

Instead of:

```
▪ Element1
▪ Element2
```

Comment: Add global CSS for lists within a div with a specific class, create a template which wraps the list in that class.

Comment: @Tgr, thanks for your comment. Any example of template which wraps the list in a div.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Tgr said, the best way is to define a CSS class for your list, and then create a template that wraps your list in a div with that class.

For demonstration purposes, I'll show you how to use a circle marker, as plus signs aren't one of the default options for `list-style-type`, and therefore take more effort to set up.

First, add the following to `MediaWiki:Common.css`:

```
.circle-list li {
  list-style-type: circle;
}
```

Then create `Template:Circle list` with the following code:

```
<div class="circle-list">
{{{1}}}
</div>
```

To use the template on a wiki page:

```
{{Circle list|1=
* Foo
* Bar
* Baz
}}
```

(The `1=` is not required on wiki pages, but it will prevent the output from breaking if your list contains a `=` sign.)

For how to tweak the CSS to display plus signs instead of circles, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3200249/html-list-style-type-dash) should get you started.

Comment: thanks a lot for your example. I used it to make my [ListPlusMinus template](https://wiki.bananeatomic.fr/wiki/Mod%C3%A8le:ListPlusMinus)