# How to convert LaTeX item to dash

Tags: latex, pandoc

I'm trying to create an epub file from a LaTeX file with pandoc. For the environment `\itemize` in LaTeX, pandoc create a list with round bullets but  I need to have dashes instead because it is a dialog.

I tried to use the package enumitem in LaTeX and

```
\setlist[itemize]{label={--}}
```

but it doesn't work.

I think there is an option in pandoc, or to put in my tex file but can't find it.

Answer (score 1):

EPUB is basically a zipped HTML file. To style HTML, you have to use CSS. For some list items that's easy with [list-style-type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/list-style-type). For the [dash, less so](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3200249/html-list-style-type-dash).

Put the following in styles.css:

```css
ul {
  margin: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}
ul > li {
  text-indent: -5px;
}
ul > li:before {
  content: "-";
  text-indent: -5px;
}
```

then use it with [pandoc's --css option](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#option--css):

```
pandoc input.tex -o output.epub --css styles.css
```