# How to create a ul with horizontales lines between each li?

Tags: html, css, forms

I **have this**:

```html
<ul>
    <li>bullet point</li>
    <li>bullet point</li>
    <li>bullet point</li>
</ul>
```

How can I achieve to **add horizontales lines** like this to it: [image: prevew]

Comment: Did you try any code? Can you share it as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used a combination of `padding`, `::before` and `background-gradient`, where I put the black `::before` element on top of the gray striped gradient. The positive effect of using background-gradient is that the number of stripes adapts to the content.

```css
ul {
  --spacing-half: 0.5rem;

  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0px;
}

li {
  padding-left: 3rem; 
  padding-bottom: 3rem;
  position: relative;
}

li {
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom,
      transparent var(--spacing-half), transparent var(--spacing-half),
      #cccccc var(--spacing-half), #cccccc calc(var(--spacing-half) + 3px),
      transparent calc(var(--spacing-half) + 3px));
     
  background-repeat: repeat-y;
  background-size: 11px 1rem;
  background-position: calc(var(--spacing-half) + 2px) 0px;
}

li::before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: var(--spacing-half);
  top: var(--spacing-half);
  height: 3px;
  width: 15px;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>bullet point</li>
    <li>bullet point</li>
    <li>bullet point</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Nice but hard to understand :)

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

CSS originally from [HTML list-style-type dash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3200249/html-list-style-type-dash) with modifications using [Horizontal Line Extension](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+23AF)
and [Horizontal bar](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+2015)

```css
ul {
  margin: 0;
}

ul.dashed {
  list-style-type: none;
}

ul.dashed>li {
  text-indent: -5px;
}

ul.dashed>li:before {
  content: "⎯ ";
  text-indent: -5px;
}

ul.dashed>li.smaller:before {
  content: "―";

  text-indent: -5px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="dashed">
  <li>bullet point</li>
  <li class="smaller"></li>
  <li class="smaller"></li>
  <li class="smaller"></li>
  <li>bullet point</li>
  <li class="smaller"></li>
  <li class="smaller"></li>
  <li class="smaller"></li>
  <li>bullet point</li>
</ul>
```