# How to know the browser compatiblity of list-style-type: "-"?

Tags: browser, compatibility

I want to use dash as the listing indicator. There are many on this, such as [HTML list-style-type dash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3200249/html-list-style-type-dash)

However, it seems that there is a much simpler way, i.e., using:

```
list-style-type: "-"
```

But not many mention this method. So I think this may be a new feature and not compatible with old browsers. I check https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/list-style-type#browser_compatibility but cannot find this information.

So, how can I know the compatibility of this statement?

Comment: That `"-"` is a kind of `<string>`, so the table does contain information about it.